# Why is the functor that associates to a scheme $S$ the set of $S$-isomorphism classes of elliptic curves over $S$ not representable?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, etale-cohomology, representable-functor

A few days ago I heard an online presentation about elliptic curves and the presenter claimed that the functor which assigns to a scheme $S$ the isomorphism classes of elliptic curves over $S$ is not representable, and it seemed this was taken for granted by everybody.

Can anybody explain to me why this is the case or give a good reference?

Comment: There are elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ which are isomorphic over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ but not isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}$. For example the so called quadratic twists $dy^2 = x^3 + ax + b$

Comment: Why does that imply the non-representability of that functor?

Comment: @TheThinWhistler Because it implies that this functor is not a sheaf for the etale topology, which every representable functor is.

Comment: It seems to me that I have a gap in my knowledge here, can anybody give me a good reference for this? @AlexYoucis

Comment: It seems to me that I have a gap in my knowledge here, can anybody give me a good reference for this? @Mummytheturkey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll elaborate a little on my comment, this answer is not really formal, but it gives the idea which can be made so.

Suppose that your functor were represented by a scheme $X$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, say. Then take two points $p, q \in X(\mathbb{Q})$ corresponding to a pair of elliptic curves $E_p$ and $E_q$ which are nontrivial quadratic twists. Then $p, q$ are distinct, since the twist is nontrivial.

But since $X$ represents our moduli problem, $p$ and $q$ must be the same point in $X(\bar{\mathbb{Q}})$ because they become isomorphic over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$. This is absurd, because $X$ is a scheme, and schemes are nice.

Comment: I see. Could you explain a little more if you could just explain a little more what you mean by nice or tell me a reference where this is explained, I would be grateful.

Comment: I just mean that the fact (which is clear in the case of varieties embedded in some projective space) that $X(\mathbb{Q}) \subset X(\bar{\mathbb{Q}})$ in a natural way, and that if you were so inclined, you could chase all the definitions to make the above work.

Comment: I don't see why this should be an injection.

Comment: If $L$ is an extension of $K$ then we have $K \to L$ inducing $Spec(L) \to Spec(K)$. Thus a $K$-point $Spec(K) \to X$ gives rise to an $L$-point. c.f., [Stacks Project Tag 01J5](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01J5)